# Swift SKSpriteNode with UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, skspritenode, paintcode

I've a problem with creating an SKSpriteNode with an UIImage.
I'm creating the assets I use for my App with PaintCode (PaintCode creates a Swift file with drawing methods and image methods which allow me to display the created images).

My problem now is that I want to create a simple SKSpriteNode using my PaintCode images but I don't know how to add them to the SpriteNode.

I tried something like this (line 18):

```
let Bottom = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(image: StyleKitName.drawBottom(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50), isWinter: false)))
```

But it returns following error:

```
/Users/myMacName/Documents/App Development/AppName/AppName/GlobalFunctions.swift:18:44: Cannot find an initializer for type 'SKTexture' that accepts an argument list of type '(image: ())'
```

The StyleKitName.drawBottom function returns an UIImage.
It would be nice if anyone could tell me how to create a SKSpriteNode with an UIImage.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you use ```let Bottom = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(image: StyleKitName.drawBottom(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50), isWinter: false)))``` this line of code?

Comment: This line of code is line 18 and the error appears in the same line.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have a UIImage, you can make a sprite node with it likewise:

```
let Image = //do your setup here to make a UIImage
let Texture = SKTexture(image: Image)
let Sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture:Texture)
```

Im not sure where or how you called the methods, but I can assure that these are the correct initializers.

Comment: Thanks this helped me to realize that I called the wrong function ("drawButton" instead of "imageOfButton" which was created by PaintCode). And sorry for wasting your time with such a stupid mistake.

Comment: glad you figured it out!

Comment: "small" upgrade to the question - same for extended UIImage with a gif? This is a big problematic as the image will have to be asynced so in this answer `SKTexture` will always get an error.. I know that no one requested it and Im sorry.. still would be nice to get an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want connect it from Scene Editor

```
    let movieImage = self.childNode(withName: "MovieImage") as! SKSpriteNode?
    let Image = UIImage(named: "imageName")
    let Texture = SKTexture(image: Image!)
    movieImage?.texture = Texture
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an iPad and want to assign UIImage to SKSpriteNode

```
let myImage = SKSpriteNode(texture:SKTexture(image: UIImage))
```

Now you can import images from files app on iPad and easily assign images to it.