# SKtexture using SF Symbol as image

Tags: xcode, swiftui, sprite-kit

Is it possible to somehow use SF Symbols in Spritekit as an SKTexture or any other type of SKNode?

I can obviously say:

```
let texture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "newTexture")
```

but not...

```
let texture1= SKTexture(systemName: "line.3.crossed.swirl.circle.fill")
```

any ideas to get round this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31906480/7129318) help?

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59886426/creating-an-skspritenode-from-the-sf-symbols-font-in-a-different-color)